# How to use CommandLineRunner in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I try to set data to database by `CommandLineRunner` interface.

If I remove everything about `bank` instance and save `account` with null list of banks, it saves data to database.

Bean class with `CommandLineRunner`:

```
@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        List<Bank> banks = new ArrayList<>();
        Bank bank = new Bank("Приват Банк", 5000.0f);
        Bank bank2 = new Bank("UkrsibBank", 3000.1f);
        banks.add(bank);
        banks.add(bank2);
        bankAccountRepository.save(bank);
        bankAccountRepository.save(bank2);
        Account account = new Account(15000.2f, 1200.5f,  banks);
        accountRepository.save(account);
    }
```

My entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "total_balance")
    private float totalBalance;

    private float cash;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "account_banks", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bank_id") )
    private List<Bank> banks;

    public Account(float totalBalance, float cash, List<Bank> banks) {
        this.totalBalance = totalBalance;
        this.cash = cash;
        this.banks = banks;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Bank implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    @Column(name = "account_balance")
    private float balance;

    public Bank(String name, float balance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

What is my mistake? 
Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: 
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set cascade type for this relation as `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`
When you call `accountRepository.save(account)` Hibernate tries to persist its related entities (Banks), but before that, you manually saved them yet(after that they are in detached state). This causes an error.
I think there are three possible solutions for this:

- Remove cascade strategy at all if you want to persist your entities independently.
- Persist `Bank` entities transitively with `Account`

```java
Bank bank = new Bank("Приват Банк", 5000.0f);
        Bank bank2 = new Bank("UkrsibBank", 3000.1f);
        banks.add(bank);
        banks.add(bank2);
        Account account = new Account(15000.2f, 1200.5f,  banks);
        accountRepository.save(account);
```

- Decorate method `run` with `@Transactional` annotation to guarantee your entities to be in persistent state